# Angular Interface Inheritance

Tags: angular, interface

I have 2 interfaces where I want to establish inheritance, How can I reference 
person.car.mileage in [(ngModel].
Below is the stackblitz link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fny9zs?file=src/app/app.component.html

I want it as { color:'red', Car: { mileage: 222 }} this is the format I want to send it to the backend

Thank you!

Comment: Please add the code here (from your `customer.ts`, `app.component.html` and `app.component.ts` for visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a few things wrong. First, your `Customer` doesn't need to extend car, if you have a car as a property. So just

```
export interface Car {
  color: string;
  mileage: number;
}

export interface Customer {
   name?: string;
  age?: number;
  sex?: string;
  car: Car;
}
```

Second, you actually need a model on that component, with at least a car property as an object:

```
export class AppComponent {
  person: Person = {
    car: {
      color: '',
      mileage: 0,
    },
  }
}
```

Then your form will work.